# HTML5 java script XMLHttpRequest status 0 and responseText is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call web service in html5 javascript. But XMLHttpRequest status value getting ZERO insted of 200 and responseText is empty. help me to solve the issue, My code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xhr;
function Getdet()
       {        
           try {

                   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                   xhr.open('POST', "URL", true); // URL-->Webservice link
                   xhr.send();
                   xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
                   xhr.responseType = 'json';
               }
    catch(err)
    {
                alert(err.message);
    }
}


function processRequest(e) {
    try{        
    var prn=JSON.stringify(e);
    alert("xhr.readyState-->"+xhr.readyState);
    alert("xhr.status-->"+xhr.status);
    alert("xhr response-->"+ xhr.response);
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {         
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            alert(response.ip);
        }
     }
     catch(err)
        {
        alert(err.message);
        }
     }
 }

</script>
```

Comment: You pass actual URL in `xhr.open('POST', "URL", true);`?

Comment: Yes Perumal i am passing acrual url only ex,http://122.222.22.22:8080/testweb/listAllUser,

Comment: I can able to get response via google postman in same webservice link

Comment: Is the url you are calling on the same domain as your ajax request?

Comment: hi Philipp , that web service developed by java

Comment: Is there any cross platform issue.?

Comment: Yeah. Maybe. I'm not exactly sure about it. Better use developer tools in Chrome to analyse what's going on during ajax request.

Comment: I would guess you are trying to do a cross-domain XMLHttpRequest. Which means you are trying to send a request to a foreign domain. (foreign = not the one from which you are sending the request). You can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy There are also ways mentioned how to fix it

Comment: As Philipp mentioned, cross-site request may not be allowed through ajax for some domains.

Comment: thanks perumal and Philip, lets try and update the status

Comment: Hi perumal, while inspecting in chrome getting below exception

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: i deployed my html script file in to host tomcat server, Now got 200 response, I installed tomcat in some other PC and execute same, this time ZERO respone,